# How to use read next() starting from any line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm trying to start reading some file from line 3, but I can't.

I've tried to use `readlines()` + the index number of the line, as seen bellow:

```
x = 2
f = open('urls.txt', "r+").readlines( )[x]
line = next(f)
print(line)
```

but I get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 441, in <module>
    line = next(f)
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

I would like to be able to set any line, as a variable, and from there, all the time that I use `next()` it goes to the next line.

IMPORTANT: as this is a new feature and all my code already uses `next(f)`, the solution needs to be able to work with it.

Comment: `readlines()` reads _all_ lines from the file. There is no `next()` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (uses [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)):

```
from itertools import islice

f = open('urls.txt', 'r+')
start_at = 3
file_iterator = islice(f, start_at - 1, None)

# to demonstrate
while True:
    try:
        print(next(file_iterator), end='')
    except StopIteration:
        print('End of file!')
        break

f.close()
```

`urls.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output:

```
3
4
5
End of file!
```

This solution is better than `readlines` because it doesn't load the entire file into memory and only loads parts of it when needed. It also doesn't waste time iterating previous lines when `islice` can do that, making it much faster than @MadPhysicist's answer.

Also, consider using the `with` syntax to guarantee the file gets closed:

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # do whatever
```

Comment: Thanks. My list has 5 urls. I got this error:
`http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.uol.com
http://www.nytimes.comTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 454, in <module>
    print(next(file_iterator), end='')
StopIteration`

Comment: @rafasalo That's not really an error, it just means the end of the file has been reached. I assumed your file was longer, so I printed lines 3-7 just to demonstrate. I fixed it so it prints until the end of the file.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem of the answer above. When I print I get all the list from the line that I've set. I would like just the next line printed, and everytime that I place `next()`, I get the next one and so on. Any idea?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Are you sure you are calling `next(file_iterator)` and not `next(f)`?

Comment: yes.
`from itertools import islice

f = open('urls.txt', 'r+')
start_at = 3
file_iterator = islice(f, start_at - 1, None)

# to demonstrate
while True:
    try:
        print(next(file_iterator), end='')
    except StopIteration:
        print('End of file!')
        break

f.close()`

Result:

`MB:user $ python3 test.py 

http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.uol.com
http://www.nytimes.comEnd of file!`

Comment: As output I would like:
Output:
3

Comment: I simply put that block there for demo purposes. replace the whole `while` loop with just `print(next(file_iterator), end='')` to get only one line.

Answer (score 0):

The `readlines` method returns a list of strings for the lines. So when you take `readlines()[2]` you're getting the third line, as a string. Calling `next` on that string then makes no sense, so you get an error.

The easiest way to do this is to *slice* the list: `readlines()[x:]` gives a list of everything from line `x` onwards. Then you can use that list however you like.

If you have your heart set on an iterator, you can turn a list (or pretty much anything) into an iterator with the `iter` builtin function. Then you can `next` it to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

The line you printed returns a string:

```
open('urls.txt', "r+").readlines()[x]
```

`open` returns a file object. Its `readlines` method returns a list of strings. Indexing with `[x]` returns the third line in the file as a single string.

The first problem is that you open the file without closing it. The second is that your index doesn't specify a range of lines until the end. Here's an incremental improvement:

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[x:]
```

Now `lines` is a list of all the lines you want. But you first read the whole file into memory, then discarded the first two lines. Also, a list is an iterable, not an iterator, so to use `next` on it effectively, you'd need to take an extra step:

```
lines = iter(lines)
```

If you want to harness the fact that the file is already a rather efficient iterator, apply `next` to it as many times as you need to discard unwanted lines:

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for _ in range(x):
        next(f)
    # now use the file
    print(next(f))
```

After the `for` loop, any read operation you do on the file will start from the third line, whether it be `next(f)`, `f.readline()`, etc.

There are a few other ways to strip the first lines. In all cases, including the example above, `next(f)` can be replaced with `f.readline()`:

```
for n, _ in enumerate(f):
    if n == x:
        break
```

or

```
for _ in zip(f, range(x)): pass
```

After you run either of these loops, `next(f)` will return the `x`th line.

Comment: I've tried this one:
`x = 2
with open('urls.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for _ in range(x):
        url = next(f)
        print(url)`

But I'm getting the FIRST and the SECOND line, I would like just the SECOND LINE, and if I place another `NEXT(F)`, I would like just the third line. Any idea?

Comment: @rafasalo. You didn't do what my answer suggests. The loops discard lines. *After* that, you can call `next` or whatever you want. You don't do it in the loop.

Comment: @rafasalo. I added a note at the end to explain.

Comment: @rafasalo, if you're going to post Python code in comments, indicate newlines clearly with `\n` or `;` and indentation levels with `\t`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to use an iterator to print the first line:

```
In [1]: path = '<path to text file>'                                                           

In [2]: f = open(path, "r+")                                                    

In [3]: line = next(f)

In [4]: print(line)
```

This code will allow you to print the lines starting from the *x*th line:

```
In [1]: path = '<path to text file>'

In [2]: x = 2

In [3]: f = iter(open(path, "r+").readlines()[x:])

In [4]: f = iter(f)                                                             

In [5]: line = next(f)

In [6]: print(line)
```

Edit: Edited the solution based on @Tomothy32's observation.

Comment: Files are already iterators, so you don't need to call `iter` *twice* on it. Also, you can't slice iterators, so `f = iter(open(path, "r+").readlines())[x:]` will error out with `TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 My bad. Will fix the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `next(f)` as many times as you need to. (There's no need to overcomplicate this with `itertools`, nor to slurp the entire file with `readlines`.)

```
lines_to_skip = 3

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for _ in range(lines_to_skip):
        next(f)

    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
% cat urls.txt
url1
url2
url3
url4
url5

% python3 test.py
url4
url5
```